# Acumatica 2020 R2 Cant detect manufacturing reference

Tags: c#, acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have a customization project from acumatica 2019 r1 and this is working but the company required the acumatica version to be the latest version 2020 r2 upon my publsh of the customization project it is looking for the reference for a table of manufacturing version 2020

```
>     \App_RuntimeCode\QuoteMaint.cs(715): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AMEstimateReference' could not be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> \App_RuntimeCode\QuoteMaint.cs(1174): error CS0246: The type or
> namespace name 'AMEstimateItem' could not be found (are you missing a
> using directive or an assembly reference?)
> 
> \App_RuntimeCode\QuoteMaint.cs(1174): error CS0246: The type or
> namespace name 'AMEstimateItem' could not be found (are you missing a
> using directive or an assembly reference?)
> 
> \App_RuntimeCode\QuoteMaint.cs(1174): error CS0246: The type or
> namespace name 'AMEstimateItem' could not be found (are you missing a
> using directive or an assembly reference?)
> 
> \App_RuntimeCode\QuoteMaint.cs(1225): error CS0246: The type or
> namespace name 'AMEstimateReference' could not be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> 
> \App_RuntimeCode\QuoteMaint.cs(1225): error CS0246: The type or
> namespace name 'AMEstimateReference' could not be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> 
> \App_RuntimeCode\QuoteMaint.cs(1225): error CS0246: The type or
> namespace name 'AMEstimateReference' could not be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> 
> \App_RuntimeCode\QuoteMaint.cs(1225): error CS0246: The type or
> namespace name 'AMEstimateReference' could not be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> 
> \App_RuntimeCode\QuoteMaint.cs(1233): error CS0246: The type or
> namespace name 'AMEstimateItem' could not be found (are you missing a
> using directive or an assembly reference?)
> 
> \App_RuntimeCode\QuoteMaint.cs(1233): error CS0246: The type or
> namespace name 'AMEstimateItem' could not be found (are you missing a
> using directive or an assembly reference?)
> 
> \App_RuntimeCode\QuoteMaint.cs(1233): error CS0246: The type or
> namespace name 'AMEstimateItem' could not be found (are you missing a
> using directive or an assembly reference?)
> 
> \App_RuntimeCode\QuoteMaint.cs(1233): error CS0246: The type or
> namespace name 'AMEstimateItem' could not be found (are you missing a
> using directive or an assembly reference?)
> 
> \App_RuntimeCode\QuoteMaint.cs(1233): error CS0246: The type or
> namespace name 'AMEstimateItem' could not be found (are you missing a
> using directive or an assembly reference?)
> 
> \App_RuntimeCode\QuoteMaint.cs(1233): error CS0246: The type or
> namespace name 'AMEstimateItem' could not be found (are you missing a
> using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

the error happend all over my customization project. it cannot find a reference to any manufacturing module. and i cant publish the manufacturing customization where i think is already included in 2020 r2. is it possible to place my 2019 r1 customization project on the latest 2020 r2. of not can you tell me what to say the our client

UPDATE:
Here is the using of QuoteMaint.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using PX.Common;
using PX.Data;
using System.Collections;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.CM.Extensions;
using PX.Objects.AR;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.TX;
using PX.Objects.SO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.Extensions.MultiCurrency.CR;
using PX.Objects.Extensions.SalesPrice;
using PX.Objects.Extensions.Discount;
using PX.Objects.Extensions.SalesTax;
using PX.Objects.Extensions.ContactAddress;
using Autofac;
using System.Web.Compilation;
using PX.Data.DependencyInjection;
using PX.Objects.Common.Discount;
using PX.Objects.EP;
using PX.Objects.CR.Standalone;
using PX.Objects.CR.DAC;
using PX.LicensePolicy;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.CR;
```

this is the part of the code that i want to use manufacturing module of acumatica 2020 r2

```
   foreach (AMEstimateReference aMEstimate in PXSelect<AMEstimateReference, Where<AMEstimateReference.opportunityID, Equal<Required<AMEstimateReference.opportunityID>>>>.Select(Base, quote))
           {

}
```

Comment: Please add the using statements and declaration of the QuoteMaint.cs to the question

Comment: ive added the using and declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2020 R2 the `AMEstimateReference` is inside the `PX.Objects.AM` library.
Just add it to your project and add `using PX.Objects.AM;`

[image]